# Why is VS giving me Disassembly when I have the .Net debug symbols?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, disassembly, symbol-server

I'm trying to get to the bottom of an annoying problem with EventViewer, so I've hooked up an instance of VS (2013) to mmc.exe and breaking on exceptions.

VS only gives me the disassembly, even though it's pointing at `System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(string)`, and the Modules window says that `mscorlib.dll` (2.0) is loaded **with** the symbol file (twice, as it happens, once in DefaultDomain, and once in EventViewer domain).

Failing that, could anyone help me work out what the offending `Path` is, starting from the Disassembly?

Comment: Having symbols does not mean you have source. Symbols for a module just means a debugger can determine more information (eg. method name) from execution address.

Comment: @Richard, that's a shame. I'm pretty sure that sometimes I do end up stepping into code that is not mine, what is the extra sauce in that case?

Comment: And couldn't it at least send me to ReferenceSource.microsoft.com?

Comment: Source servers can be used, and there is inbuilt support (if enabled) to handle parts of the BCL source.  [2nd comment] Enabling source server support, disabling my code (both in debugging options) will integrate BCL source debugging.

Comment: You are not going to get source code for .NET 2.0.  It isn't that useful anyway, CheckInvalidPathChars() does not have a bug.  Just check the argument passed to the method.

Comment: @HansPassant, AH!, that's the missing detail, everything makes sense. It's not me passing the path in, unfortunately, that's the last part of the question...